# Extending Sitecore User Profile - Which Field Types Can I use?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have created a custom user profile in Sitecore 6.4.1, and am trying to add a basic droplist to the users profile. It seems that no matter which type of field I add to the user profile, it renders out in the Edit User dialog as a plain text field. Is there a restriction to the user profile, or some other method I need to use to allow content editors to pick an item to associate with a user profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user manager cannot properly render all fields types. You should stick to single line text values if possible and avoid the user manager interface to edit the info itself. Use it more as a custom data store.

**Edit**: for reference, I've used this feature and extended profiles with simple fields for a login-based system with Sitecore. Our site allows users to register an account, which creates extranet users with an "extended profile" in the Core DB. When these users access thier profile page on the front-end site when they're logged into the front-end, they can edit basic data, like name, address, etc. I store these basic data points in the custom profile SLT fields, so its used merely as a data store. No one actually edits the content from the Sitecore shell's user manager.